# grant all on a nested table in ORACLE 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a nested table in schema OE and I want to grant ALL rights to another user.
I have used:

```
grant all on OE.SUBCATEGORY_REF_LIST_NESTEDTAB to user_name;
```

but I received the following error:

> grant all on OE.SUBCATEGORY_REF_LIST_NESTEDTAB to test Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-22812: cannot reference nested table column's storage
>   table
>   22812. 00000 -  "cannot reference nested table column's storage table"
>   *Cause:    An attempt to access the nested table column's storage table is
>              not allowed in the given context.
>   *Action:   Issue the statement against the parent table containing the
>              nested table column.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried granting rights on the type definition?